# Retrieving job submit limit

Tags: slurm

Due to submitting too many jobs, I got the following error message:

> sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job violates
>   accounting/QOS policy (job submit limit, user's size and/or time
>   limits)

How can I retrieve "job submit limit" so that I can submit new jobs only after previous maximum amount of jobs are completed?

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command:

```
sacctmgr list user $USER withassoc
```

You should see the limit on submitted jobs under column `MaxSubmit`

Comment: In the output table, there is nothing under`MaxSubmit`.

Comment: @Shibli, were you able to solve it?